# How to come back to the same page from Detail view?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-9.x

I have an extension with a 'list'-view/-action and paginated display (using the fluid paginate VH).
From each item there is a link to the detail view (`show` -view/-action).

In the show view there is a `back` link. it's only a simple jump to the general list view:

```
<f:link.action action="list">Back to List</f:link.action>
```

I want to jump back to the same page in the paginated output, where the detail call was originated.

I could extract the page number of the paginated view and transmit it to the call of the detail view, so I have it in the detail view.
But how can I generate a working back link?
It would need an URL-paramter like `?extensionplugin[@widget_0][currentPage]=123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is a little bit complicated notation because of the `@` in the index of the parameter and because the parameter is indexed two levels deep:

```
<f:link.action action="list" arguments="{'@widget_0':'{currentPage:page}'}">
    Back to Liste
</f:link.action>
```